# How to manage recurring tasks in taskwarrior?

Tags: to-do, taskwarrior

I am having troubles understanding how to manage recurring tasks in [taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/)

I start with an empty database:

```
$ task
[task next]
No matches.
```

I add a recurring daily task:

```
$ task add recur:daily due:later test
```

It shows up in the report:

```
$ task
[task next]

ID Age Recur Due   Description Urg 
 2 -     P1D 19.2y test         2.4

1 task
Creating recurring task instance 'test'
```

If I mark it done like this:

```
$ task 2 done
Completed task 2 'test'.
Completed 1 task.
$ task
[task next]
No matches.
```

it disappears from the report. I believe it makes sense, since "I completed the daily task today".

The problem is it never appears again the next day and further. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you marking it done? If it is a repeating task it is never done ...

Comment: @DavidPostill what should I do then to not see it in the report till tomorrow, once I complete it today?

Comment: Read [Taskwarrior - How Recurrence Works](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/recurrence.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill I did it before resorting to ask on SE, it doesn't answer my question at all. It contains details about internal workings rather than a perspective for the end user that solves a practical problem (like mine). I fail to see where in that document is it explained how to manage recurring tasks properly

Comment: So ask the developers. As there are no other taskwarrior questions on [su] you probably won't get an answer here.

Comment: @DavidPostill this really looks like you're trying to bully me out of this site

Comment: Not at all. I'm just advising you that there may be no other taskwarrior users on this site..

Comment: @a.t. There are only [4 answers](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=taskwarrior%20is%3aanswer) posted **before** the OP's question (1 by you which has nothing do do with taskwarrier specifically, and 2 stating they use, or will use  taskwarrier). That only leaves 1 answered question. I stand by my assertion (which was posted 2 years ago).

Answer (score 9):

I was messing around with recurring tasks and figured it out:

Some background: Creating a recurring tasks creates a `parent` task which spawns `child` tasks. 
from: https://taskwarrior.org/docs/recurrence.html

with some testing, I've found that with this command:

```
    (ins)[>]task add "test" recur:5s due:30s
    Created task 27 (recurrence template).
```

Firstly, `due` affects the first child task.  Every child task spawned after *due-time (30 seconds in my example)* then is due in *recur-time (5 seconds in example)*

```
    (ins)[>]task
    [task next]

    ID Age Deps P Project Recur Due  Description
    22 -                   PT5S 30s  test

    #some time later...

    (ins)[>]task
    [task next]

    ID Age Deps P Project Recur Due  Description
    22 60s                 PT5S -30s test
    23 30s                 PT5S -25s test
    24 25s                 PT5S -20s test
    25 20s                 PT5S -15s test
    26 15s                 PT5S -10s test
    27 10s                 PT5S -5s  test
    28  5s                 PT5S -    test
    29  0s                 PT5S 5s   test
```

However `due` also affects one more thing: **when the second child task is
spawned** (the second child task is due in *recur-time* so the third child task spawns
after *recur-time* and so on).

This is why you aren't seeing your second child task since you have the due
date set to `later` which is `19.2 years` time in the future according to your example; the
second child task will therefore spawn only after `19.2 years` time later (after which
each child task will spawn `daily`).

Comment: Nice! How am I supposed to "end" a recurring task? Just delete the parent task / recurrence template?

Comment: when you delete any of them it should ask you if you want to delete all of them or not:

"This is a recurring task.  Do you want to delete all pending recurrences of this same task? (yes/no)"

Answer (score 4):

I [previously answered this same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636312) over in unix & linux. RPosting the answer again, for record.

---

Before I dive into the working details, note that recurrence is not [well-designed](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/design/recurrence.html). What I bring is empirical observations and liable to change with a rework.

#### TLDR; How do I use and make sense of recurrence

```
task add recur:<duration> due:<first task due date> until:<delete first task by date> wait:<date when task will appear> "my task"
```

Example:

- `task add recur:daily due:9:00 until:12:00 wait:5:00 eat breakfast`
- Eat breakfast at 9:00 AM
- Hide task until 5:00 AM
- Remove task by lunch time
- Create a new occurrence everyday

#### Details

Recurrence requires a `due` attribute (enforced with a [validation check](https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/commit/8e34a0281111000933ae2b55c27abeb036501568#diff-ed89bfc63927e96eabc804aec9363663c3bcd6a297f062eb27d7c332b58ee225R1089)).
Recurrence can also use `until` and `wait` attributes, if they exist.
Recurrence does not use `scheduled`.
And there is a `mask` attribute, that tracks which instance of the reoccurence the task is.

When a new recurring instance is created:

- `new task due` = `parent due` + `recur` * `mask`
- identical math for both `until` and `wait`
- `scheduled` is copied wholesale from the parent task. In practice, this unexpected behaviour won't break your workflow, just affects filters and skews urgency. I call this out because it took me a very long time to discover this was not working as expected.

Every time `taskwarrior` runs, it checks to see if it's time to create the next occurrence. The psuedo-equation is:

```
now >= due + recur * (mask + 1)`
```

Note, there is a config value, `rc.recurrence.limit`, that can be used to tell taskwarrior to create even more occurrences further out.

You can expect the next occurrence to be created at the due date of the previous.